# Does addition not work properly if used on indexes?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, coding generally and while doing a specific project I got stuck here :

```
Guess_1 = input()
Number_2 = input()
Set_dead_1 = set()

def teste_dead_1():
    index_1 = 0
    while index_1 <= 3:
        if Guess_1[index_1] == Number_2[index_1]:
            Set_dead_1.add(Number_2[index_1])
        else:
            pass          
        for i in Set_dead_1:
            print(i, "is dead.")        
        index_1 += 1  
teste_dead_1()
```

For further explanation I am trying to compare each char of each string and if it is a match type that char "is dead."
but the problem is when I execute my program and insert the numbers, something like this pops up:

```
 >1234
 1234
 1 is dead
 2 is dead
 1 is dead
 3 is dead
 2 is dead
 1 is dead
 4 is dead
 3 is dead
 2 is dead
 1 is dead
```

But I want it to write :

```
 >1 is dead
 2 is dead
 3 is dead
 4 is dead
```

Thanks for your comprehension!

PS: the two 1234s are the one I typed

Comment: First `else: pass` is useless. Then indentation matters in python: take your `for...: print` block out of the while loop.

Comment: Thanks, it worked but the order is wrong as it states for me 3 then 2 then 1 then 4, and should i just leave it empty instead of typing else: pass ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to include `else` at all

Comment: @SaikoNoHero1 if one of the answers here helped, please accept them. Else continue dialogue as to the problem not being solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took the time to copy your code and run it. I debugged it with an `if` check on the input length. The major issue is your `for` loop was incorrectly placed and running for each iteration of your while loop. I would write this down on paper if you do not understand the iteration process.

Amped up code:

```
Guess_1 = input()
Number_2 = input()
Set_dead_1 = set()

def teste_dead_1():
    index_1 = 0
    Guess1Length = len(Guess_1)
    Number2Length = len(Guess_1)
    if Guess1Length < 3 or Number2Length < 3:
        print('Input must be more than 3 characters')
        return False
    while index_1 <= 3:
        if Guess_1[index_1] == Number_2[index_1]:
            Set_dead_1.add(Number_2[index_1])
        index_1 += 1
    for i in Set_dead_1:
        print(i, "is dead.")
    return True
teste_dead_1()
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, you don't need a loop to print your set. Print the new members of the set as you add them in

```
Guess_1 = input()
Number_2 = input()
Set_dead_1 = set()

def teste_dead_1():
    index_1 = 0
    while index_1 <= 3:
        if Guess_1[index_1] == Number_2[index_1]:
            Set_dead_1.add(Number_2[index_1])

            print(Number_2[index_1], "is dead.")

        else:
            pass 

        index_1 += 1           

teste_dead_1()
```

Comment: @SaikoNoHero1 This still breaks the single purpose principal, which I feel like OP may not understand. I would not follow this suggestion. If you want to `print` each item, it should really be in its own function altogether...

Comment: @T.Woody I agree with you, but isn't your way adding to big O?

Comment: No. Big O notation is only representative for the functions main loop. Here, the main loop is the users while loop.